# Dropping keys - Can anyone suggest an alternative to a straight physics simulation?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I'm trying to do an animation which includes dropping a set of keys on the table.  No matter what I try, the physics engine fails.  Just running a simple simulation of keys hanging on a ring fails.  The keys dance and jiggle and frequently explode off the ring. The settings I use are shown below. The actual keys use default values with a mesh collider, 50% friction, and 0 margin. I've tried every suggestion I've read about.  I've even set the steps per second to 1000 and the solver steps to 100 thinking that more steps would produce a more accurate result.  In some cases, this just makes everything worse.

So, unless someone sees something I'm missing, I'm just giving up on the physics engine for any kind of interactive simulation.  Can anyone point me in a better direction?   I've tried playing with physics constraints, but haven't been able to figure out a way to allow the keys to move around a ring and constrain their spinning.

Thanks in advance.

[image: example][image: rigid body world settings]

Comment: What are your settings in the physics panel? Have you applied transforms to all objects involved in the simulation? Perhaps consider uploading a sample file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and adding the provided link to your question.

Comment: Change keys origin to the bottom of it. This solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your and @Timaroberts input!  I had uploaded the .blend file to blenderartists and a kind soul named alank pointed out that I had an object on layer three which was interacting with the keys.  I moved it and they settled down.  Then another awesome person named PhotoX suggested that I up the scale on the objects, move the weight of the keys down to .1 and then drastically increase the damping factor to between .5 and .9.  This allowed the keys to settle down.  Unfortunately as soon as I drop the keys in the simulations, all the keys just pop off and go flying when it hits.